# Jersey Making Moxy work with Jackson

Tags: java, rest, jackson, jersey-2.0

I want Moxy for the sake of dealing with XML and JSON stuff. However  I have a need of using @JsonIgnore in my code to ignore certain fields.

Currently I have added both the dependencies in pom.xml. However jackson is not working and all the ignore properties stopped working. What is the fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`@XmlTransient`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html). It's pretty much the JAXB equivalent of `@JsonIgnore`

> Prevents the mapping of a JavaBean property/type to XML representation.